# Molten plastic or resin over jumper terminals

Tags: soldering, terminal

I have a number of sensor boards on which I need to close two jumper connectors with solder. On the second board, my iron was not sufficiently hot and I made a mess of it. I've since replaced the iron. On the board, the solder did not adhere to the terminals and what looks like molten plastic is now covering them. Can anyone please suggest a good way forward to fix? Is it a matter of scratch away the plastic and trying again? The sensor is so tiny it's difficult. Will attach a photo of the GY-BNO055 board with the two open terminal pairs marked.

[image: sensor]

And this is how the the GY-BNO055 boards look normally with terminals open (image from Aliexpress):

[image: Open terminals]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your photo it is not clear how the "jumper" looks like. If it is like two pads to be shorted together, then they appear a little too far apart (they look like they are meant to host a resistor or other kind of component).

If my guess is correct it will be quite difficult to bridge the pads with a single solder joint, especially because there is solder mask between the pads.

If they are meant to be shorted at all, probably they are designed to be shorted using a 0Ω resistor during the pick and place phase of board manufacturing.

To join them manually without using a 0Ω resistor you could use a single strand of (very clean or maybe tinned) copper wire across them to act as a "guide" for the solder.

Pretinned wire-wrapping wire (AWG 30) is great for such things, once you remove its insulation. For example like this:

[image]

In this way you can help the solder to spread across the gap, otherwise surface tension will force the solder to split in two clumps, one on each pad.

Caveat: since the thing is so tiny you'll need a firm hand and some soldering skill (and a way to hold the board stuck to your workbench).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. They need to be soldered for i2c or left open for serial transfer. Here's a link with photo of the terminals in open state: https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/BoIAAOSwo4Rizn~N/s-l1600.jpg I managed to solder one board successfully, but this one no.

Comment: @sebinho You should add that photo to your question (with proper attribution), so that people can see the details. Anyway, although the situation is not as extreme as I guessed from your photo, the trick I mentioned can also be used in your case if you find it difficult to short the pads just with a blob of solder. BTW remember to clean your solder tip very well.  And also clean the pads from residues of old solder (solder wick can help here).

Comment: Edited the question, hope that's what you meant. I ended up taking the board to a technician. It cleaned up well and he put a couple of tiny wires closing the terminals as you described. Unfortunately it did not work. Three other sensors that I bought from another supplier fortunately all arrived with terminals closed. And they work, as does another that I managed to close myself. Have resolved to buy a replacement from the second supplier.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your message properly.  Will add the photo later.

Answer (score 2):

This "plastic" could be flux. Try some isopropyl alcohol to wipe it off.

Comment: Thanks, will try

Answer (score 1):

I would be almost certain that is flux. Depending on how hot it got / which exact flux, it might be squishy or brittle. You might be able to scratch it off, but Isopropyl Alcohol and a stiff brush is the safest way. Or if you have anything calling itself flux remover, or PCB cleaner that might help.

That much flux would suggest to me that you're using the wrong solder for the job, or too much. Exactly what you're doing wrong is a bit unclear, but I'd guess that you're placing the iron on the board, and then flooding with a large amount of solder to try and bridge the gap. What you're seeing is all the flux from that solder being deposited on the board. For a gap of that size, you're going to struggle to bridge with just solder, and the solder will want to follow the iron's heat when you remove it. You can try a "wiping" action where you drag the iron away quickly, across the pads rather than straight up, but I'd probably grab a zero-ohm resistor or a bit of wire. You could for this, get quite a longer bit of wire than you need, so you can hold it (with tweezers/pliers) away from the joint, make the bridge, then trim it to length.

You do need to clean it off, as that much will start to hinder your soldering.